# HTTP methods: DELETE vs POST

Tags: http

Let's say I have a resource called "Session". The client would call PUT to create and begin a new session. When the client is finished with the session, it should no longer be accessible, but should persist for historical/accountability reasons.

To end the session, would it be more appropriate to issue a DELETE request, which would seem semantically closer to the desired effect, or POST, seeing as the resource isn't actually removed permanently?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The question here is: Is the request [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Examples)? If you execute the same request twice, does it have a side effect? Like when you order an article, executing the order request twice would get you the article twice.

In that case, `POST` is the method you want. If not, then you want either `PUT` or `DELETE`.

As you don't seem to be deleting the session, only altering its state, `PUT` would be a better method, because it means that the resource is altered, and not deleted, which is the case in your case.

*Edit:*

If the resource appears to be deleted from the client, `DELETE` seems more appropriate. How things are implemented in the back doesn't matter for the client.

Comment: What if the resource "appears" to be deleted, from the client's perspective? In my example, the request would be idempotent, because calling it a second time wouldn't have any side effects and issuing a GET request on the session would fail.

Answer (score 0):

POST request will be better here as you don't actually delete the `session`. POST requests are often used to change state of an object. It is your case I think.