# Multiple @RequestMapping (value, method pairs) in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to achieve something like this with Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{userId}", method =  RequestMethod.DELETE)
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{userId}/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void deleteUser(@PathVariable String userId) {
    ...
}
```

This would give me a common endpoint for REST calls and standard HTML form posts.
Is it possible to do with Spring MVC?
All I can come up with is

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/user/{userId}", "/user/{userId}/delete"}, method =  {RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.POST})
public void deleteUser(@PathVariable String userId) {
    ...
}
```

but the result is slightly different because a POST to "/user/{userId}" would also delete the user.

Answer (score 5):

One thing you could do is make 2 separate methods with their own `RequestMapping` annotation, and then just pass the parameters on to a different method, where you do actual stuff:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{userId}/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void deleteUserPost(@PathVariable String userId) {
    deleteUser(userId);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteUserDelete(@PathVariable String userId) {
    deleteUser(userId);
}

private void deleteUser(String userId){
    //Do things here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, got it wrong way around.

In [mature REST architecture](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html), code should use a URL to refer to a resource and use HTTP method to define the action on the resource.  So just define a `@RequestMapping("/user/{userId}/delete", method =  RequestMethod.DELETE)` and eliminate the POST.  See [DELETE vs POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217115/http-methods-delete-vs-post).